# Javascript dynamically calculate many row use one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this :

```
Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" class="txt" value="" />

Price: <input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="txt" value="500" />

Total: <input type="text" name="total" id="total" class="txt" value="" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('#qty').keyup(function() {
     var quantity = $("#qty").val();
     var priceItem = $("#price").val();
     var total = quantity * priceItem ;
     $("#total").val(total);
});
```

It's just one row. How to make function can be use to all row?

Comment: what's your `id` in other row? like `qty_2` or something?

Comment: @leonhart yes my id : qty1, qty2, ...

Comment: id should always be unique .. looks like you have same id for multiple elements

Comment: then just make the jquery selector to be `$('#qty' + index)`

Comment: @bipen my id : 
qty1, qty2, qty3...
price1, price2, price3...
total1, total2, total3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use classes? It'll give you more fine tuned control over your elements and heck, it makes coding easier :)

Manipulating ids through selectors degrades performance and makes code messy to maintain. What if you decide to add a `-` in between `qty` and `1` in `qty1`? You'd have to change that 30 times, assuming you have that `qty` field 30 times.

**Here's how your markup would look like:**

```
Qty:
<input type="text" name="qty" class="txt qty" value="" />
<br/>
Price:
<input type="text" name="price" class="txt price" value="500" />
<br/>
Total:
<input type="text" name="total" class="txt total" value="" />
```

**Your JavaScript :**

Then, in your `keyup` method:

```
$('.qty').keyup(function () {
    var sibs = $(this).siblings();
    var quantity = this.value;
    var priceItem = sibs.filter(".price").val();
    var total = quantity * priceItem;
    sibs.filter(".total").val(total);
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/bCKxW/

Comment: glad to help.. mark it as the right answer and upvote if this has helped u :)

Answer (score 0):

If your `input fields id` is looking like `qty_1`, `price_1` and `total_1`
then you can do this :

```
$('input[id^=qty]').keyup(function() {

        var quantity = $(this).val();
        var idAttr =   $(this).attr('id').split('_');
        var i = idAttr[1];
        var priceItem = $("#price_" + i).val();
        var total = quantity * priceItem ;
        $("#total_" + i).val(total);
});
```